# Customize Laravel API validation responses

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-request

I'm building a REST API with Laravel and wondering if there is a way to customize the API responses when validating.

For example, I have a validation rule in a Laravel request, saying a specific field is required.

```
public function rules() {
   return [
       'title'=>'required|min:4|max:100',
   ];
}
```

So, for this validation I get the error message in Postman like this

```
{
    "title": [
        "Please enter Ad Title"
    ]
}
```

What I want is to customize that response like this..

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Validation Error"
    "title": [
        "Please enter Ad Title"
    ]
}
```

So, that the error is more specific and clear.

So, how to achieve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't show *where* you're validating, but you can try parsing the validation response before sending it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide a custom function to the `FormRequest` class called `messages` and return an array of validation messages mapped using `dot notation` for specific messages on specific rules:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'title.required' => 'Please enter an Ad title',
        'title.min' => 'Your title must be at least 4 character'
    ]
}
```

Returning a `success` message is futile as if it fails a `422` error code will be thrown when performing an `ajax` request anyway.

As for the `message` property, you will receive that as part of the payload, wherein the actual validation errors will be contained in the object.

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm already overriding messages method with custom error messages. The thing I was confused is the `success ` message. I thought that's a must in a API response in order to identify the status.

Answer (score 5):

I got a solution for your REST-API Validation Laravel FormRequest Validation Response are change by just write a few lines of code.
enter code here

Please add this two-line into your **App\Http\Requests\PostRequest.php**

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
```

after that add this function in **your file**.

> you can change $response variable into your specific manner.

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) { 
        $response = [
            'status' => false,
            'message' => $validator->errors()->first(),
            'data' => $validator->errors()
        ];
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($response, 200)); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can customize errors, check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#customizing-the-error-format). also you can validate in this way

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title'=>'required|min:4|max:100'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        // get first error message
        $error = $validator->errors()->first();
        // get all errors 
        $errors = $validator->errors()->all();
    }
```

then add them to your response, for example

```
 return response()->json([
     "success" => false,
     "message" => "Validation Error"
     "title" => $error // or $errors
 ]);
```